# Data manipulation using Perl script

Tags: perl

Input:

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
aaa   15   23   A
bbb    7    5   B
ccc   43   10   C
```

Expected output

```
aaa  15  16
bbb   7   8
ccc  43  44
```

I know to get this using `awk` but I need to do this in Perl. I tried using an array in Perl like

```
 push(@output_array, $temp_array[0] . "\t" . $temp_array[1] .  "\n");
```

I don't know how to add 1 to the col2 and make it as col3. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: There's a program that's been distributed with Perl since forever called `a2p` for converting `awk` scripts to Perl.  (There's also an `s2p` for converting `sed` scripts to Perl.)  Maybe that would help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a perl oneliner

```
perl -lane 'print join("\t", @F[0,1], $F[1] + 1)' file.txt
```

If you want to truncate a header row:

```
perl -lane 'print join("\t", @F[0,1], $. == 1 ? $F[2] : $F[1] + 1)' file.txt
```

If you want to completely remove a header row:

```
perl -lane 'print join("\t", @F[0,1], $F[1] + 1) if $. > 1' file.txt
```

Comment: can you help me on how to do that using array?

Comment: @F its an array. Gets invoked by using the "-a" command line switch. `perldoc perlrun`

Comment: @Miller, the second one liner is not removing the header

Comment: @sara: it isn't trying to remove the header; it is echoing it with the heading of column 3 unchanged.  If you don't want the first line printed, then add `if $. > 1` between the close parenthesis and single quote of the first script.

Comment: @sara Added 3rd option for completely removing a header row instead of just truncating.

Answer (score 0):

```
push(@output_array, $temp_array[0] . "\t" , $temp_array[1] . "\t" , $temp_array[1] + 1 . "\n");
```